# "Via a phone call" or "with a phone call"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, email

In an email signature I have

> Please keep in mind that scheduling is best done **via a phone call**

or would it be better to write “**with a phone call**”? 
Customers want to use email to schedule appointments with me and it is much easier when they call me, so what is the best way to get that point across without sounding like a brat?

Answer (score 3):

"Via" makes sense, but it does not necessarily sound correct.

Here are some alternatives:

> Please keep in mind that scheduling is best done by phone.
>
> For best scheduling, please call by phone.
>
> Please keep in mind that scheduling is best done with a phone call.
>
> Please keep in mind that scheduling is best done with a voice call.
>
> A voice/phone call is the best way to schedule.

Comment: or "over the phone"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is merely a question of personal preference. For example, I personally prefer the "via" version, although the other form is also correct. I also prefer "bear in mind" rather than "keep…". This latter preference may be a US versus UK thing though.